# High Physical Reads/Temp DB utilization On Azure SQL DB VS On Premise DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, query-performance

I have an application which performance is fine on premises SQL Server. Same DB is hosted on Azure (business critical 16 Cores) but its performance is not as good as on premise when executed using JMeter performance test suite.

I figured out using query store that physical reads on Azure DB is much higher then on premise DB. Though Azure DB is having more memory then on premise DB. temp DB utilization is also quite high on Azure DB.

Execution plan is same and I have updated stats as well. Database configuration is mostly same.

OP Execution Plan -
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJQ_ox39D

Azure DB Plan -
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry1Sieh5D

Just to clarify, application is sending millions of small queries to server that's why its difficult to pin point any one particular query.

Comment: can you upload the actual execution plans to "pastetheplan" and update your question with the links?

Comment: What is the actual problem?  Have you looked at Query Performance Insight? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/query-performance-insight-use and/or the Query Store https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Problem is that It's the absolutely same code, same indexes, same configuration still performance of Azure DB is slower. I came to know that physical writes are on higher side using query store itself.

Comment: Have you looked at wait stats?  If there are lots of small queries then it may be waiting on IO, CPU or network.

Comment: Yes, I checked wait stats using query store. Top 3 wait categories on Azure side are 

Lock (Average 363, total 50192), 
Parallelism (Avg 1822, Total 14579), 
Network IO (Avg 35, Total 14579). 

OP Side top 3 waits are 

Parallelism (Average 2745.5, Total  5491)
Network IO (Average 53.22, Total  14049)
Other Disk IO (Average 48.73, Total  9453)

Comment: Just to take a step back, why do you expect the performance of SQL Server and Azure to be the same when they are completely different DBMSs?

Comment: Client is thinking about moving their on premise DB to cloud. But they found performance gap between OP and Azure DB and both of them are based on SQL server. As part of my assignment, I need to explain why there is performance gap between OP and Azure. Hope it explains?

Comment: Assuming that the other suggestions people have made don't reveal any issues (mis-configuration, lack of indexes, etc.) then the reason there is a performance difference is because they are not the same DBMS and therefore would not be expected to perform the same. Azure SQL might be based on SQL Server but it is different - if you want identical performance then run SQL Server in a VM on Azure. However, if you want to improve performance of Azure SQL (beyond what performance tuning can give you) then you can just scale it up - that's one of the main benefits of running stuff in the cloud.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Actually increasing cores have helped the cause. Is there any recommendation about what should be Azure configuration in comparison to on-premise configuration? Right now our on-premise database is running 16 core. 16 core Azure DB configuration performance is at least 25 to 30% slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 16 cores are physical and dedicated to your SQL Server. They might be idle most of the time. If hyper-threading is enabled, you might have 32 logical cores for added compute capacity for some workloads. You might feel guilty for allocating the money for resources you don't need, but it is better to have more than less because more could require a new server.

An Azure host might have 32 cores with hyper-threaded enabled. The 64 logical cores are not going to be idle. You get 16 vCPUS. If these are provided by 8 hyper-threaded physical cores, I would expect a performance drop of the 20-30% you see for most loads. For light loads you will not notice much difference. For heavy loads, it might be much worse. You might regret not spending the money for resources you need, but it's easy to fix.

Forget apples and oranges. How many cats does it take to run a 16 dog process?

I think v2 is from the time a core was a core.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/sizes-memory?toc=/azure/virtual-machines/linux/toc.json&bc=/azure/virtual-machines/linux/breadcrumb/toc.json

Comment: There's AMD in the mix too with it's hyper-threading, so the vCPU can be quite the mongrel.